# How to find quaternion or (pitch, roll, yaw) given a mapping for rotated rigid body?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, rotations, rigid-transformation

My question is regarding [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/222170/1082431) on finding the orientation of a rigid body given 3 points.

Given $x\mapsto QP^{-1}x+(Q_1-QP^{-1}P_1)$ how do you determine the euler angles? I need pitch, roll, and yaw.

Heres the specific part of the answer I'm talking about.

**More information, easier computation**

Suppose you want to map $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^3$ to $\{Q_i\}_{i=1}^3$, and the distances between the $P_i$'s and $Q_i$'s are the same. Compute a fourth point by
$$
P_4=P_1+(P_2-P_1)\times(P_3-P_1)
$$
and
$$
Q_4=Q_1+(Q_2-Q_1)\times(Q_3-Q_1)
$$
Then create the matrix $P$ whose columns are $P_2-P_1$, $P_3-P_1$, and $P_4-P_1$.

Also create the matrix $Q$ whose columns are $Q_2-Q_1$, $Q_3-Q_1$, and $Q_4-Q_1$.

Then $x\mapsto QP^{-1}x+(Q_1-QP^{-1}P_1)$ maps the source points to the destination points.

EDIT:

Or even just the quaternion in its x,y,z,w components. From there I can convert it to pitch, roll, yaw.

Comment: Can I ask why on Earth are you using Euler or Tait-Bryan angles, when versors or bivectors are simpler and easier to use to describe orientation and rotations, and do not suffer from gimbal lock?  Friends do not let friends use Euler/Tait-Bryan angles, you see.

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose the api that im using requires you to specify 3d rotation in pitch, roll, yaw in terms of the world frame of reference. After some more research I found that "euler angles" and "pitch, roll, yaw" are not synonymous.

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose I edited the question asking for a quaternion.

Comment: The rotation matrix is $QP^{-1}$. The rest of it is the translation, which has nothing to do with orientation. What API are you using that accepts pitch, roll, and yaw but won't accept a rotation matrix?